# .net MVC 3 upload file and set file mask

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i'm wondering is that possible to indicate the mask for file type by default we can upload all file types . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the standard HTML file input control you cannot specify masks. There are some components such as [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) which allow you to specify this mask. Obviously all those can be faked on the client so if you really need to reliably ensure that the uploaded file is of given type is to do this on the server side.